# gmp gives error using mpz_pow function

Tags: c++, gmp, exponentiation

I'm trying to exponentiate large bit numbers using the gmp library `mpz_ui_pow_ui()` but the mpz_class values that I pass in give me the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘mpz_ptr {aka __mpz_struct*}’ to ‘long unsigned int’ [-fpermissive]
mpz_ui_pow_ui(cipher.get_mpz_t(), pTxt.get_mpz_t(), e.get_mpz_t());
```

All the values being passed in are mpz_class types. Why am I getting the error, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html

> — Function: void mpz_ui_pow_ui (mpz_t rop, unsigned long int base, unsigned long int exp)

The function takes `unsigned long`, not `mpz_t`.

Comment: It's so weird that **arbitrary precision arithmetics library** uses __normal__ values around.

Comment: @Slav there is another function that takes the base as arbitrary precision. Using an exponent that does not fit unsigned long (or some variant on weird platforms like win64) on a base that isn't 0 or ±1 would yield a result that cannot fit in memory.

Comment: What's that another function? Sad thing I had to **mpz_pow_ui(..., exp.get_ui() )**, but **mpz_pow_ui(...., exp )** would look cleaner. Aesthetics aside, there could be use-case with say swap memory to hard drive and just perform computations with actually exponents having >32 bits.

Comment: Since this question was about `mpz_ui_pow_ui`, `mpz_pow_ui` **is** the other function. If I ever add a pow/powi function to gmpxx.h, I'll make it accept mpz_class as exponent, but in C it makes more sense to have only the _ui function. And no, there are no use cases for an exponent that doesn't fit a builtin integer type (though on weird platforms like win64 this should be long long instead of long).